# Monitor HttpClient data - don't post data on subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to work out a way monitor the result of a `HttpClient.Post` `observable` from 2 locations without posting data to my server twice.

I've created an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aau9mg

---

At the moment I have a `app.service` which gets data from the server and then on return of the data, sets a value:

```
public getDump():Observable<any> {
    var observable = this.http.get("https://angular-http-guide.firebaseio.com/courses.json");

    observable.subscribe(
      data => this.someValue = 99,
      error => console.log(error)
    );

    return observable;
  }
```

Then, in the `app.component` I want to disable the post button (`dumpInProgress`) and then on retrieving data, set `dump`.

```
getDump(){
    this.appService.getDump().subscribe(
      (data) => this.dump = data,
      () => { },
      () => this.dumpInProgress = false
    );
  }
```

---

So this currently works completely as expected and achieves the desired results. The issue I am having that is if you check the network logs when you click the get dump button, you will see that the request is made twice! This is because:

> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all HttpClient methods. [Source](https://angular.io/guide/http#always-subscribe)

So is it possible to achieve this result without making a second get request?

Comment: It's really late here, will respond in the morning.

Comment: updated stackblitz link

Comment: @RahulSingh , he is subscribing twice , not a issue of preflight request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is `map` function :

```
public getDump():Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("https://angular-http-guide.firebaseio.com/courses.json").map(
        data => { this.someValue = 99; return data; },
        error => console.log(error)
    );  
}
```

> The reason behind 2 request are ,
>
> ```
> this.appService.getDump().subscribe(...)
> observable.subscribe(...)
> ```
>
> This 2 lines of code , you are making 2 calls by subscribing it twice
>   .

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-double-subscription-issue)**

Comment: Yeah I worked that out with the double subscribe. This is the fastest correct answer I've ever had! You nailed it, thanks!

Comment: @Zze , Thanks for the appreciation , Happy Coding BTW :)